# SQL, Find orders where strict critera is met, Match item, not if other items purchased

Tags: mysql, sql

I have stumped all the IT people at my work with this one, so wondeirng if anyone can help.

I need to extract from an order table anyone who has only purchased a specific product type, (if they have order the product type and any other product types i dont want to know who you are)

for example the table is roughly

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Order ID    |    item code      |      Name       |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           |   ADA             | item 1
2           |   ADA             | item 1
2           |   GGG             | item 2
3           |   ADA             | item 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So i want to find all the order IDs of people who only purchased item code ADA, BUT not if they purchased over items, so the output of this query should be order ID 1 & 3 and skipping order 2 as this had a different item.

Would really appriciate it if anyone could help.

Comment: Would it be possible for OrderID 1 to have 2 records with the same item code ADA? Also what database is it - MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle?

Comment: How do you join customers to the order?

Comment: The general form of this type of query is called "relational division" - there are two main variants, depending on whether you want an exact match (as here) or will allow other rows in addition.

Comment: This doesn't actually seem too hard.  Select the ones with only one order (select distinct order_id, count(*) as cnt from orders having cnt=1).  And then you only use the id's from that query.

Or the other way round - get a list of the ones that have ADA and then see which ones have >1` product in the order.  Look at the syntax for "where X in (select ...)"

Comment: Hi, sorry im basically learning sql as i go as there are not enough staff here with time to show, So the Database is MySql. the customer field is available (sorry i should have included that,) its just under customer ID.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current explanation and example, the below should work. However, there are outstanding questions in the comments which may change the actual correct solution.

```
SELECT
  O.OrderId, MAX(itemCode), MAX(Name)
FROM
  Orders O
  INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT
     OrderId
    FROM
      Orders
    WHERE
      itemCode = 'ADA') ADA
   ON
     O.OrderId = ADA.OrderId
GROUP BY
  O.OrderId
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming an order can't have multiple records with the same ItemCode, you could use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Orders 
WHERE OrderID IN (
   SELECT OrderID 
   FROM Orders
   GROUP BY OrderID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
AND ItemCode = 'ADA'
```

If an order could have multiple records with the same ItemCode then you'd have to change the `SELECT *` to `SELECT DISTINCT *` and then `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT ItemCode)`